# NodeJS JWT Verify Fail even token if it's the same as the sign token

Tags: node.js, jwt, express-jwt

Trying to develop my API on NodeJS, I get my sign token and send it back on secure api routes, but the jwt is never valid even if it's the same token I generated! What is wrong in my code ?

I did my sign that way

```
pbkdf2(queryPassword, salt, 10000, length, digest, (err: Error, hash: Buffer) => {
  if (hash.toString('hex') === userPassword) {
    sign({'user': username, permissions: []}, secret, {expiresIn: '7d'}, (err, token => {
      response.json({'token': token});
    }));
  } else {
    response.json({'error': 'User / Password Mismatch'});
  }
});
```

Here is the verify:

```
verify(token, secret, function(tokenError, decoded) {
    if (tokenError) { // i'm always getting error...
        return response.status(403).json({
            message: 'Invalid token, please Log in first'
        });
    }

    next();
});
```

here is my Angular2 service that request data from my API

```
let headers = new Headers({'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.token});
let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
this.http.get(apiUrl, options);
```

token generated by sign:

eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyIjoidHQiLCJwZXJtaXNzaW9ucyI6W10sImlhdCI6MTQ4MzExNTAzNCwiZXhwIjoxNDgzNzE5ODM0fQ.bJbH4619JAU8pf_6qcYl0V1V5PxWsPBRYeXbeb6VL_M

token received by http service:

Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyIjoidHQiLCJwZXJtaXNzaW9ucyI6W10sImlhdCI6MTQ4MzExNTAzNCwiZXhwIjoxNDgzNzE5ODM0fQ.bJbH4619JAU8pf_6qcYl0V1V5PxWsPBRYeXbeb6VL_M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found my error....

In my angular2 Api i was using this line

```
let headers = new Headers({'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.token});
```

i need to send only

```
let headers = new Headers({'Authorization': this.token});
```

the 'Bearer ' was causing me the error...